# how to center li elements as grid view's

Tags: html, css

I have the following [code](http://jsfiddle.net/Zd9Gf/). It's essentially a simple grid view that uses `<ul>` and `<li>` tags. I wanted to make it responsive such that the `<li>` elements are always centered no matter what the width of the screen is. How can I do so? I've tried setting the `padding-left` and `padding-right` as percentages, however it doesn't work. Right now if I adjust the width of the screen it doesn't always stay centered.

Comment: You should use media queries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add `text-align: center` to the parent `<ul>`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hRaDS/)

Answer (score 0):

I'll extend on the previous answer...

Also center the UL

```
#home-listing {
  text-align: center;
    width:80%; /*Pick Your Own Width*/
    margin:16px auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zd9Gf/3/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by centered. In order to center the entire list you could do something like:

```
ul {
    padding: 0px;
    width:500px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/Zd9Gf/2/).

Answer (score 0):

add this class:

```
ul.search-results{
    width:100%;
}
```

and update this class:

```
ul.search-results li {
border-right: 1px solid #cecdcb;
border-bottom: 1px solid #cecdcb;
border-top: 1px solid #fff;
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
    width:60%;
    margin:0 20%;
    text-align:center;
}
```